# pointer to integer

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, integer, nsnumber, nsinteger

I have an array of integer and i'm trying to get an element from the array; xcode keeps showing this message: "initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast"

I know that this warning means that i can't alloc integer to pointer type, and i'm asking how ca i get that element, or if there is a solution to convert pointer to integer

Here is my code:

```
NSString *pathvalidrep = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"validrep" ofType:@"plist"];   
NSArray *tabreponses = [[NSArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:pathvalidrep] retain]; 
truerep = tabreponses;
[tabreponses release];

NSUInteger val1 = [truerep objectAtIndex:0]; //the warning apears here
```

thanx for help :)

Answer (score 2):

Elements of the array are probably [NSNumber](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html) objects...  And the warning is appearing because of this, you assign a pointer to `NSNumber` to a `NSUInteger`.

Try :

```
NSUInteger val1 = [[truerep objectAtIndex:0] integerValue];
```